Failed to Setup Npm Proxy to Connect to Remote Npm Storage Through a Proxy
I have been working for a week on a npm proxy in nexus (version: OSS 3.47.1-01) that connects to a remote npm storage behind a proxy server, and I still failed to make it work. Here is the network topology:
| <----------------inner network---------------------> | <----------outer network----------> |
MyComputer <----> Nexus (Npm Proxy) <----> (10205) Proxy Server <----> (80) Remote Npm Storage

The port configured in the Proxy Server for redirecting npm requests is 10205, and the Proxy Server should redirect all the npm requests to port 80 of the Remote Npm Storage. When configuring the Npm Proxy in Nexus (through a website frontend), the Remote storage field is set to http://ProxyServer:10205/aa/bb/cc. But when I try to use My Computer to pull packages from Remote Npm Storage, e.g. by npm install, I find that Nexus sends fetch requests to port 80 of the Proxy Server instead of port 10205. For examples, it is expected that the Npm Proxy in Nexus sends requests to http://ProxyServer:10205/aa/bb/cc/xyz.tgz to pull xyz.tgz, but it actually send the requests to http://ProxyServer:80/aa/bb/cc/xyz.tgz, which leads to connection failure.
I have no idea what cased the port changed.
I have tried two different workarounds that can make things work:

Change the configured port of Proxy Server to 80: When configuring the Npm Proxy in Nexus, the Remote storage is set to http://ProxyServer:80/aa/bb/cc. In that case, I can download npm packages in My Computer through Nexus.

Bypass Nexus: I also tried connecting directly to Remote Npm Storage via Proxy Server, which bypasses nexus. Here are the settings in my .npmrc file:


registry = http://RemoteNpmStorage:80/aa/bb/cc
proxy = http://ProxyServer:10205
https-proxy = http://ProxyServer:10205

In that case, I can also download npm packages in My Computer through Nexus. One interesting finding is that, if I set registry in the .npmrc file to the Proxy Server, I get the same problem (i.e., port changed) as the one when using Nexus:
registry = http://ProxyServer:10205/aa/bb/cc

Besides, a third workaround that might work is that: 1) I set the Remote storage of the Npm Proxy to http://RemoteNpmStorage:80/aa/bb/cc; and 2) I add some repository-specific proxy settings such that the Npm Proxy could communicate with the Remote Npm Storage through http://ProxyServer:10205. What I can find in Nexus frontend is that, under Administration > System > HTTP > ProxySetting, we can change the proxy settings for the entire Nexus. However, the Npm Proxy is not the only repository in Nexus, I cannot change the global proxy settings as that affects all the repositories in Nexus.
Any help or hint would be highly appreciated. Thanks!
